# What are the possible issues when running a PHP script for a long time

Tags: php, memory, time, ini

I am developing a PHP web application for photographers.

A normal process would be a photographer uploads a folder of approx 1000 High res images by FTP and then clicks a button in the browser. At this point my script is triggered which resizes the image into 3 sizes.

Currently on my localhost this process is taking about 2 seconds to produce 1 image (resizing down from images about 2.5MB in size) So we can estimate that for 1000 images we are talking 30 - 40 minutes.

Can I set my `max_execution_time` php_ini setting to 45 minutes. Or is this a bad idea? What would you reccommend for something like this.

Comment: are you gong to run this local host live? if not check your hosting provider allows this, many don't. But if you run your own hosted servers this should not be an issue, i run scripts for hours, and php daemons perminatly. Make suer you clean up the memory used as php will only free it at the end of the script run.

Comment: no I am not going to run this locally. But I do have full control over the server it will be run on. I am using codeigniter framework's image library - which I believe frees the memory when needed.

Comment: the only suer-fire way of knowing if it is going to work is to test it, you can check cpu\memory usage as it runs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using GD to resize images - then it is a time to move to [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Comment: GD is terrible for resizing images, but then ImageMagick is not too efficient either (it is fast, but only because it uses multiple threads.) The most efficient way to resize an image is ExactImage (econvert).